# How do I add an EventListener, to delete an li after being clicked on?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

This is my code so far:

```js
const list = document.getElementById("list")
const enter = document.getElementById("enter")

enter.addEventListener("click", add => {
  var input = document.getElementById("form").value
  var node = document.createElement("LI")
  var text = document.createTextNode(input)
  node.appendChild(text)
  list.appendChild(node)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-Do:</h1>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>A test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="form" type="text"></input>
    <button id="enter">Add</button>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I was already able to add a list element when I click on the add button, but I do not know how to add an EventListener to each separate li element.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I edited the content, now with html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. bind one event to the container (the list)
2. ensure the element clicked (target) is what you want (e.g., an LI)
3. `remove()` that element, if so

This can be done with:

```
document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.matches('li'))
    target.remove()
}, false);
```

## Working Example

```js
const list = document.getElementById("list")
const enter = document.getElementById("enter")

enter.addEventListener("click", add => {
  var input = document.getElementById("form").value
  var node = document.createElement("li")
  var text = document.createTextNode(input)
  node.appendChild(text)
  list.appendChild(node)
})


document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
  if (target.matches('li'))
    target.remove()
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To-Do:</h1>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>This is</li>
    <li>A test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="form" type="text" />
    <button id="enter">Add</button>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Plain JS delegation

Add the eventListener to the UL to delegate the click even on dynamically inserted LIs:

```
document.getElementById("ul").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() == "LI") {
    tgt.parentNode.removeChild(tgt); // or tgt.remove();
  }
});
```